# Get all value of attribute from each Element from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```xml
<HeadercardUnit EndTime="2065-25-45 20:32:44" StartTime="2065-25-45 20:32:23" Rejects="NO" MilliSec="1" Currency="USD" DeclaredDepositAmount="0" denomvalue="1" DepositID="" CustomerID="" HeaderCardID="">
    <Counter Number="2" Currency="USD" Output="Stacked" Quality="Accepted" Issue="2006" Value="5" DenomID="" DenomName="5 USD-2006"/>
    <Counter Number="31" Currency="USD" Output="Stacked" Quality="Accepted" Issue="2000" Value="1" DenomID="" DenomName="1 USD-2000"/>
    <Sum Number="33" Currency="USD" Output="Stacked" Sum="41.00"/>
</HeadercardUnit>
```

I try to parse it with this code:

```
string[] content = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\", "*.xml");
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(content[0]);

XElement xml1 = XElement.Load(content[0]);

string xml2 = xml1.ToString();
//Console.WriteLine(xml2);
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xml2);
var counter = xdoc.Descendants("Counter").Count();
var data = from bps in xdoc.Root.Descendants("Machine")
           let Param = bps.Element("ParameterSection")
           let Opt = Param?.Element("Operator")
           let Hcl = Param?.Element("HeadercardUnit")
           let Count = Hcl?.Element("Counter")
           select new
           {
               Type = (string)bps.Attribute("Type"),
               SerialNum = (string)bps.Attribute("SerialNumber"),
               Startime = (string)Param?.Attribute("StartTime"),
               Endtime = (string)Param?.Attribute("EndTime"),
               Opt = (string)Opt?.Value,
               Number = (string)Count?.Attribute("Number")
           };

foreach (var pcl in data)
{
    MessageBox.Show(counter.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        LogService(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}",
            pcl.Type, pcl.SerialNum, pcl.Startime, pcl.Endtime, pcl.Opt, pcl.Number));
    }
}
```

The result only give me one line which is looping two time because the counter tag have two elements looks like this:

```
BPSC1,309322,2065-25-45 20:32:23,2065-25-45 20:32:44,User1,2
BPSC1,309322,2065-25-45 20:32:23,2065-25-45 20:32:44,User1,2
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? Where did you stuck? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Peter Csala i want the second line from the result is coming from second counter tag on xml which containing 31

Comment: You can call `xdoc.Descendants("Counter").Skip(1)` if you want to ignore the first element. Or if you are explicitly want to get the `Counter` which has the 31 as its `Number` then `xdoc.Descendants("Counter").FirstOrDefault(element => (string)element.Attribute("Number") == "31")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to give a definite answer given you've omitted a portion of the XML that would allow this to be reproduced. However, this line:

```cs
let Count = Hcl?.Element("Counter")
```

Gets the *first* `Counter` element. If you want all of them (as you suggest), then you need to iterate through those:

```cs
from Count in Hcl.Elements("Counter")
```

This will then create an object in `data` for each `Counter` element.

Answer (score 0):

i added the line inspired by @Charles Mager

```
from bps in xdoc.Root.Descendants("Machine")
from Countx in bps.Descendants("Counter")
```

then i can call all attributes